# Cant access get results from fetch API request

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

I've been trying to access the array results from my fetch API request. I can get the results to return and parse it from JSON into a JavaScript object. However I cant access the results. The array is that is return called results. I wondering what I'm missing. The ultimate aim of the project is to get 12 random profiles from the API and get it to display to the card div. The error message I'm getting is:

> 'Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined at app.js:40'

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <title>Public API Requests</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link href="css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>


        <header>
            <div class="header-inner-container">
                <div class="header-text-container">
                    <h1>AWESOME STARTUP EMPLOYEE DIRECTORY</h1>
                </div>

                <div class="search-container">

                </div>
            </div>
        </header>

        <div id="gallery" class="gallery">

        </div>


    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
const gallery = document.getElementById('gallery');
const card = document.createElement('div');
card.classList.add('card');
gallery.appendChild(card);

function fetchData(url) {
    return fetch(url)
            .then(response => { return response.json()})
            .then(data => {console.log(data)})
            .catch(error => {console.log('Error with fetching API', error)})
          }

function generateInfo(data) {

   const info = data.map( item => `
    <div class="card-img-container">
        <img class="card-img" src="${data}" alt="profile picture">
    </div>
    <div class="card-info-container">
        <h3 id="name" class="card-name cap">${name.first} ${name.last}</h3>
        <p class="card-text">${data.email}</p>
        <p class="card-text cap">${location.city}</p>
    </div>
    `)

    card.innerHTML = info;
  }

fetchData('https://randomuser.me/api/')
  .then(data => generateInfo(data.results));
```

Comment: What do you expect `.then(data => {console.log(data)})` to `return`?

Comment: Hello mate! Thank you for replying. An array of Objects parsed from JSON. Sorry this is the first time I've dealt with fetching API's so I'm blundering around in the dark.

Comment: I've added the code tags in my comment for a reason (especially the second) ;)

Comment: <3 <3 <3 <3 Thank you fella. However no its coming back undefined. I will see what i can do about this. Cheers dude!

Comment: If you _"add"_ `return data;` then it shouldn't return `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear, the object you are getting in `data` is not defined, that's why it does not have a `result` key.

Check that data is coming from the URL. When I fetch the URL there is JSON coming in.

Also note that in the second `then` you have for debugging is not returning the `data` variable, and that's why you get nothing afterwards.

Add a return statement like: `return data;`

Extra info related to the `catch` part from docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API if you want to check for errors look at the status code from response.

> The Promise returned from fetch() won’t reject on HTTP error status even if the response is an HTTP 404 or 500. Instead, it will resolve normally (with ok status set to false), and it will only reject on network failure or if anything prevented the request from completing.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. What would you suggest to improve the answer?

Comment: Does it look better now @andreas?

Comment: The fix is (imho) still "hidden" in the answer but yes. At least it now has a fix ;)

Answer (score 0):

Change the fetchData function, remove .then block  where you are getting final data, attach it when calling fetchData

```
function fetchData(url) {
    return fetch(url)
            .then(response => { return response.json()})
            .catch(error => {console.log('Error with fetching API',               
error)})}




fetchData('https://randomuser.me/api/')
   .then(data =>generateInfo(data.results)); //success to the final promise
```

Now inside generate info use foreach() instead of map().Since for each user object you need to create card.

```
function generateInfo(results) {
   results.forEach( userObj =>{
    const card = document.createElement('div');
    card.classList.add('card');
    card.innerHTML = `
    <div class="card-img-container">
        <img class="card-img" src="${userObj.picture.thumbnail}" alt="profile picture">
    </div>
    <div class="card-info-container">
        <h3 id="name" class="card-name cap">${userObj.name.first} ${name.last}</h3>
        <p class="card-text">${userObj.email}</p>
        <p class="card-text cap">${userObj.location.city}</p>
    </div>
    `;
    gallery.appendChild(card);
    })
 }
```

Run the following snippet to check if it works.

```js
const gallery = document.getElementById('gallery');
function fetchData(url) {
    return fetch(url)
            .then(response => { return response.json()})
            .catch(error => {console.log('Error with fetching API',               error)})}
function generateInfo(results) {
   results.forEach( userObj =>{
    const card = document.createElement('div');
    card.classList.add('card');
    card.innerHTML = `
    <div class="card-img-container">
        <img class="card-img" src="${userObj.picture.thumbnail}" alt="profile picture">
    </div>
    <div class="card-info-container">
        <h3 id="name" class="card-name cap">${userObj.name.first} ${name.last}</h3>
        <p class="card-text">${userObj.email}</p>
        <p class="card-text cap">${userObj.location.city}</p>
    </div>
    `;
    gallery.appendChild(card);
    })
 }
fetchData('https://randomuser.me/api/')
  .then(data =>generateInfo(data.results));
```

```html
<header>
            <div class="header-inner-container">
                <div class="header-text-container">
                    <h1>AWESOME STARTUP EMPLOYEE DIRECTORY</h1>
                </div>

                <div class="search-container">

                </div>
            </div>
        </header>

        <div id="gallery" class="gallery">

        </div>
```

Comment: _"Now inside generate info use foreach() instead of map()."_ - Why? OP generates the markup for all "cards" and then adds them once with `.innerHTML = info`

Comment: Since for each user object he needs to create card. and info is an array  we cant do directly innerHTML=info...thoughts?

Comment: _"we cant do directly innerHTML=info"_ - We absolutely can. `.innerHTML` expects a string hence this triggers an implicit call of `.toString()`

Comment: ok that will work but output will be in singe div class="card"  and inside this div there will be lot of divs with "card-img-container" and "card-info-container" .isnt that wrong

Comment: Your method can be done but op does have to embed "div class="card" inside string while mapping objects

Comment: Only OP can answer this. I've only added my 2 cents on your _"use `.forEach` instead of `.am`"_ part ;)

Comment: sure . i will make edits accordingly according to his answer

Comment: Regardless thank you both very much for your time! Really sorted things out for me and where I was going wrong. Thank you again! @Supercool

Comment: @Andreas sorry can only tag per comment

Comment: so you found the solution? @RandyBeans